# Convert List<T> to BlockingCollection<T>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert `List<T>` to `BlockingCollection<T>` and here's my code..

```
List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>
    {
        new Job() {Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="test1" },
        new Job() {Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="test2" },
        new Job() {Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="test3" },
    };

BlockingCollection<Job> coll = jobs as BlockingCollection<Job>;
```

And `Job` class is defined as..

```
public class Job
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This type casting doesn't seem to work. Is there any easier and performance efficient way to convert `List<T>` to `BlockingCollection<T>` without looping through the list and explicitly adding each list item to the collection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`BlockingCollection<T>` provides a constructor which accepts an `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`. You can therefore leverage an `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` implementation which has an efficient `IEnumerable<T>` copy mechanism such as `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

```
List<Job> jobs = new List<Job> {
    new Job { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "test1" },
    new Job { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "test2" },
    new Job { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "test3" },
};

BlockingCollection<Job> col = new BlockingCollection<Job>(new ConcurrentQueue<Job>(jobs));
```

This avoids the (rather significant) locking overheads associated with adding items to the collection one by one.